# How modify value of attributes passed into Grails GSP

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I require to be able to change the value of a bean (attribute)
passed into a gsp. Am using grails 2.3.11.

see code below - this does not modify the bean - please can you inform how it can be done?

At line #1 this is an attempt to replace the attribute with a new value -
so that Venue -> Xenue. 
At line #2 this shows that the value has not changed.

```
// locns.gsp
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
    <head>
        ...
        <script type="text/javascript">
            <g:each in="${locns}" status="i" var="locn">
                var x = '${locn.addr1}'.replace("V", "X");
                locn.addr1 = x;                     #1
            </g:each>
        </script>   
    </head>
    <body>
        <g:each in="${locns}" status="i" var="locn">
            ${locn.addr1}                           #2
        </g:each>
    </body>
</html>

// Controller:
def locns() {
    Locn[] locns = new Locns[2];
    locns[0] = new Locn();
    ...     
    locns[0].addr1 = "Venue Point"; 
    locns[0].addr2 = 'London';
    ...
    [locns:locns]
}

// attribute / bean class   
class Locn {
    public String addr1;
    public String addr2;
    ...
}
```

Thank you, Steve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this (even though it is dicouraged and your controller should handle this)

```
at #1
<g:each in="${locns}" status="i" var="locn">
<% def locnChanged = new ArrayList<>() %>
<% def x = locn %>
<% x.locn = locn.addr.replace("V", "X") %>
<% locnChanged.add(x) %>
</g:each>

at #2
<g:each in="${locnChanged}" status="i" var="locn">
${locn.addr1}
</g:each>
```

No need for javascript there. But once again, you shouldn't take care of that in the GSP.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up client and server side logic here.  First, the GSP tags execute on the server side to generate HTML which is sent to the browser, and only *then* does the generated JavaScript execute in the client browser.  The GSP will produce some HTML that looks something like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
    <head>
        ...
        <script type="text/javascript">

                var x = 'Venue Point'.replace("V", "X");
                locn.addr1 = x;                     #1

                var x = 'Venue 2'.replace("V", "X");
                locn.addr1 = x;                     #1

        </script>   
    </head>
    <body>

            Venue Point                           #2

            Venue 2                           #2

    </body>
</html>
```

The JavaScript will then fail with an exception at the first line #1 because you're trying to set a property on an undefined value.